# How to insert and extract image or object from cxRichEdit

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress cxRichEdit for Notebook project.

I need to be able to insert an image selected from open dialog into richedit (now I can do that only by pasting from clipboard), and, if needed, get this image back to original file with original extension.

Please advise.

Comment: You name it! Use clipboard manipulation.